# Can you embed a separate pdf into Indesign and open it after exporting to PDF?

Tags: pdf, attachment, adobe-indesign

I would like to ask the following if possible. We have a client that wants a separate pdf document, embedded in a main pdf document and opens when you click it. Like the function in MS Word where you can attach another Word document inside a Word document (Word-ception, lol) and you can still open it.

I've tried it in Acrobat Pro with the Attachment and Link tools. Another option was to put the link document in an ftp server for accessibility. but our client really wants this functionality. Is this possible in Indesign?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using Word as your example vehicle there are several ways to link 2 documents.

One is an appendix to the other, in PDF terms is a merge or binding but its one flowing document with separate sequential sections/chapters.

Another way is to link to an external file, in PDF terms a hyperlink to a relative second file, which can be locally folder relative or a web absolute reference. You have tried that.

In Word we can add objects internally with icons, in PDF that can be an annotation comment attachment to save externally and action accordingly. You also seem to discount that approach.

Finally PDF offers an Adobe Specific Structure where multiple PDFs attachments can be imbedded in an overall PDF wrapper. These are called [Portfolio**s**](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/overview-pdf-portfolios.html) and not! to be confused with their [portfolio service](https://portfolio.adobe.com/)

They are unpopular since in a browser without Adobe Reader they should only offer the cover page.

[image]

Whilst in securer offline readers the files may well be shown as attachments that you need to save or independently open to view them.
[image]

Only some non Acrobat viewers may view them as a collection. And in the past that required runing insecure SWFlash, But I understand that has changed ?

Here is how the 3 internal PDF files seen above were shown in older Acrobat 9.

[image]

Possibly the best experience is using Foxit Reader
[image]